# How to know which Hudson version is used by my Jenkins server?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, hudson

I have a problem with my build on Jenkins and I think it is related to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4364

Quoting:

> I am using rhel5 with hudson 1.321
>
> The issue I am seeing is that when building maven2 projects that take less than 1 minute for their surefire tests to complete, Hudson is marking the build as failed. I've tried several versions of maven (2.2.1, 2.0.10, 2.1.0), and am able to build from the command line fine, and see the tests run (both in hudson and on the command line), but get the following error messages from Hudson when it tries to copy/validate test files:
>
> Using maven2.0.10:
>   Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.3:test': Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run?

The reported bug doesn't mention which Jenkins version it is related to (only that the Hudson version is 1.321).

I'm novice in Jenkins and don't know Hudson at all or the relation
between them (does Hudson come bundled with Jenkins?).

How can I tell which version of Hudson is used on my Jenkins server? (my Jenkins is ver. 1.599 if that's relevant).

Note: I believe the problem in my build is related to Hudson since the exception that starts with `Hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:212)`

Comment: As far as I know Jenkins split from Hudson somewhere in the late 2010... And the bug you have quoted was fixed before that... So if you are seeing the bug again now, it's most probably a regression...

Comment: If Jenkins and Hudson were split, there might be an old version of Hudson installed on our server (but I don't know how to check which version it is).

Comment: As noted, Jenkins forked from Hudson and many of the internals still use the Hudson namespace. It's likely that you're using Jenkins even though the namespace says Hudson.

Comment: In that case I guess it's regression. It's definitely the problem - I added a sleep of 60 seconds to the compilation and it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

should this help, from a linux terminal ?

```
head -5  /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml| grep -oP '(?<=<version>).*?(?=</version>)'
```